# Joining tables while using group by in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, group-by

I have two tables to join in SQL  using the ID column in both. Table 1 has only unique values of ID as follows and I want to keep all columns of this table:

```
ID     code 1    code 2      
1       123       99
2       222       09
3       344       13
```

Table 2 has multiple rows of each ID as follows:

```
ID    application_time       Application Number
 1       11jan2004                 123
 2       15oct2010                 124
 1       24nov2008                 845
 3       05sep2010                 166
 1       07feb2001                 865
 2       24aug2017                 545
 3       12mar2009                 233
 2       11dec2001                 811
```

So, from table 2, I want to add the **total count** of each **ID**, and **Min** and **Max** of **Application_time** to table 1. I also need to count the number Application Numbers that start with 8. of  I do not know where I should use **group by ()**. So the outcome should look like:

```
ID     code 1    code 2  count   Min (application_time)   Max (application_time)      
1       123       99       3          07feb2001                    24nov2008
2       222       09       3          11dec2001                    24aug2017
3       344       13       2          12mar2009                    05sep2010


Count of Application Number starting with 8
                   2
                   1
                   0
```

Comment: Incidentally, purely by convention, a column called id is usually the PRIMARY KEY for a given table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how you can do it:

```
select 
   t1.Id
   ,t1.code1
   ,t1.code2
   , count(*) count
   ,min(application_time)
   ,max(application_time)
   , sum( case when left( t2.application number, 1 ) = '8' then 1 else 0 end ) 
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
   on t1.Id = t2.Id
group by 
   t1.Id
   ,t1.code1
   ,t1.code2
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I edited the question, can you please modify your code accordingly.

Comment: Can anyone help with the number of application numbers that start with 8?

Comment: @Alex, just add another column with sum( case when left( t2.`application number`, 1 ) = '8' then 1 else 0 end ) AppsStartingWith8 --  the application number (due to the space) requires the tick-marks around it.  Typically not good to have column names with spaces.

Comment: @Alex - Drapp gave the right answer in the comment , I updated my answer based on that